# jQuery UI with touchpunch not fully working on touch devices

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm currently trying to get the jQuery UI sortable function working on my Android phone (touch). Sadly, the touch event don't works on my phone. I've tried everything.

```
jQuery("#details-inner").sortable({
    handle: ".sort-section-handle",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "sort-placeholder",
    update: function (e, r) {
        var a = {action: "update_element_position", sec: jQuery(r.item).attr("data-section"), pos: r.item.index()};
        jQuery.post(cm_ajaxurl, a)
    }
});

jQuery("#details-inner .sort-section-handle").disableSelection();
```

I've included jQuery UI and also jQuery UI Touch Punch for the mobile touch support within WordPress this way:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-sortable' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-touch-punch' );
```

On the computer everything works great but not on my phone. On the phone it's scrolling the page when I'm trying to press the handle to move the section. Any idea what could be the problem? Maybe the handle?

Comment: Is there someone who has an idea?

Comment: Please review your WP Resulting Headers in the browser. What Versions are being used? Also can you provide a lite-weight example?

Answer (score 1):

First, test with a working example without TouchPunch: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4k2zmh/14/

For Android or mobile testing, use: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4k2zmh/14/show

**HMTL**

```
<ul id="details-inner">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="sort-section-handle ui-icon ui-icon-grip-dotted-vertical"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#details-inner {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 240px;
}

#details-inner li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  height: 1.5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

html>body #details-inner li {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.ui-state-highlight,
.sort-placeholder {
  height: 1.5em;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.sort-section-handle {
  margin: .2em;
}
```

Since we know we will be working with Mobile devices, I added a bit of a margin to the handle.

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#details-inner").sortable({
    handle: ".sort-section-handle",
    axis: "y",
    placeholder: "sort-placeholder"
  });

  $("#details-inner .sort-section-handle").disableSelection();
});
```

This works fine on a desktop yet does not work on Chrome on Android (my test device). So now we add TouchPunch.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4k2zmh/15/

Mobile: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/jv4k2zmh/15/show

This works as expected. I would advise loading TouchPunch after jQuery UI. You will want to check this in your WordPress resulting output.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where do you import touchpunch? I can't see it in the HTML? And as I found it it's not working with the latest jQuery UI version so maybe this is a problem. I'm still trying to contact the developer to clarify this.

Comment: I see a Touch Punch plugin for WP: https://github.com/wp-plugins/touch-punch There is also a method to register scripts to be used by WP: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/

Comment: This is what I did but without the plugin because touch punch is included in WordPress :)